# how can we change the animation of viewPager as turning of a page

Tags: android, animation

i want to create a photo album in android, in which the next image should come as the tuning of page in album,the image is showing in the viewPager , so when we swipe for next image it should come like the page turning

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't tried anything, you should refer this https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl.

This repository contains exactly the thing you want. Just add the images in the array and you will see the page curl effect.

Comment: actually i want only one image in one view,but the page should turn like this

Comment: Please checkout the code. And run it. It is doing exactly what you are saying.

Comment: here it sowing two pages at a time but i need only one page..i need the animation only

Comment: Play with canvas and stuff. Make some changes in the calculations. There will be a definite solution.

Comment: i tried but i didn't get any solution,i need this curling effect in my viewPager